# Live messenger login with silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-live

I need to use windows messenger login to get users authenticated and get their contact details ..display name etc. Currently I am using a DLL from [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=messenger)

It works fine. But in IE8 it does not work. IE8 with win 7 or IE8 with XP. So is there any other easy way of doing it?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Windows Live is being pushed as part of the Azure platform.

[Click here](http://dev.live.com/liveid/) for some more information on Live ID.